# Installing immutable collection package in asp.net app, causes failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I add the System.Collections.Immutable library to my asp.net application, I get the following error:

The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

It's a stock generic asp.net application, targeting .net 4.5.  I added the immutable stuff via nuget.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you take the `Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable` package ?

Comment: Yah thanks, same issue and the solution worked for me also.  I had to made the System.Runtime.dll copy local though.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by just adding this two lines to my csproj file:  <Reference Include="System.Collections" />  <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />